# Word for something that can be jumped off of

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for something that can be jumped off of?  For example the ground can jumped off of, but you can not jump off something which is falling through the air. I'm looking for an adjective.

Comment: _jump-off-able_

Comment: You can jump off of any hard surface that can support your weight, and which is not level, otherwise, you are just jumping. Unless you're in space or a free-fall; then you can push off. Is there more to this question? It sounds odd to me.

Comment: I'm looking for an adjective which describes objects that are able to be jumped off of.  I know it's an odd question, but isn't this the place for that?

Comment: People *can* jump off of things falling through the air, eg if standing on the wing of a falling airplane can jump up or down relative to it.

Comment: How about "perch"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with *a jump off*? True, a jump off is usually associated with a location, as in

> The jump off point for the parachutists was ten miles south of Interstate 79, just outside Albuquerque, New Mexico.

I don't see why you can't use *jump off* in referring to an object from which you are jumping.

> The skateboarders used a specially constructed fifteen-foot-high platform as a jump off for their most dangerous stunt.

Comment: I was hoping for an adjective.  I should have been more clear in my original question.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer.  @ermanen's comment "jump-off-able" is also good and an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

To jump off of something, it must be higher than wherever you are jumping to or falling to after jumping. Therefore the word *elevation* can be used for something off which a person can jump. The ground alone, at least level ground as @ Medica observes, can be jumped from, but not off.

el·e·va·tion  [el-uh-vey-shuhn] noun

3.
an elevated place, thing, or part; an eminence.
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/elevation

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you always be able to jump off of an *edge*?

Comment: If the edge of something cannot apply an equal and opposite force to you when try jumping off it, then you can't jump off it.

Comment: @gms9rc You are correct. I'm not sure why you mention it, though; As far as I'm aware, applying an equal and opposite force to a jumper is a property of any physical substance or medium that can *have* an edge. I guess you couldn't jump off the edge of something non-physical, like the border of an arbitrary region of space... Is that the kind of edge-case you were thinking of?

Answer (score -1):

I get where you are coming from: you're looking for a synonym for a starting block of the kind that runners use. Maybe *springboard* would work?

Comment: Could you first explain the difference between "off" and "off of"?